# Make a table from a list of {{key1, key2}, value}

Tags: list-manipulation, display

I have a list mapping two keys to each element, {{key1, key2}, value}, and would like to display this as a table with horizontal headers for each key1 and vertical headers for each key2, with the values being in the cells.

For example, I would like to display

```
{{{1, 1}, 0.54}, {{1, 2}, 0.85}, {{1, 3}, 0.24}, {{2, 1}, 0.43}, {{2, 2}, 0.99}, {{2, 3}, 0.11}, {{3, 1}, 0.10}, {{3, 2}, 0.23}, {{3, 3}, 0.94}}
```

as:

```
    1       2       3
1   0.54    0.85    0.24
2   0.43    0.99    0.11
3   0.10    0.23    0.94
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Could you post a representative example?

Comment: @Feyre, I've added an example

Comment: If your list is called `lst`, does this work in general? `TableForm[GatherBy[lst, #[[1, 1]] &][[All, All, 2]], 
 TableHeadings -> Transpose@lst[[All, 1]]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If

```
lst = {{{1, 1}, 0.54}, {{1, 2}, 0.85}, {{1, 3}, 0.24}, {{2, 1}, 0.43},
       {{2, 2}, 0.99}, {{2, 3}, 0.11}, {{3, 1}, 0.10}, {{3, 2}, 0.23},
       {{3, 3}, 0.94}, {{4, 1}, 0.10}, {{4, 2}, 0.23}, {{4, 3}, 0.94}};
```

Then

```
TableForm[
  GatherBy[lst, #[[1, 1]] &][[All, All, 2]], 
  TableHeadings -> DeleteDuplicates /@ Transpose@lst[[All, 1]]
 ]
```

[image]

If your elements are always indexed in order, starting with 1, etc., then

```
TableForm[
  SparseArray[Rule @@@ lst], 
  TableHeadings -> DeleteDuplicates /@ Transpose@lst[[All, 1]]
 ]
```

also works.

Answer (score 2):

A bit ugly, but still can give you what you need.

```
show[list_] := 
 Module[{xvalues, yvalues, assox, assoy, tab}, {xvalues, yvalues} = 
   DeleteDuplicates /@ Transpose@list[[;; , 1]];
  {assox, assoy} = 
   Association@Thread[# -> Range@Length@#] & /@ {xvalues, yvalues};
  tab = ConstantArray[Missing[], {Length@xvalues, Length@yvalues}];
  (tab[[assox[#[[1, 1]]], assoy[#[[1, 2]]]]] = #[[2]]) & /@ list;
  Grid[Transpose@
    Prepend[Transpose@Prepend[tab, yvalues], Prepend[xvalues, ""]], 
   Dividers -> {2 -> Red, 2 -> Red}]]

show[yourlist]
```

The main idea is to create an empty list first, then filling them according to `{x,y}` in each pair like `{{x,y},value}`.

you can test this function more throughly with, check the behaviour with larger list and missing elements here:

```
show[{#, RandomInteger[{0, 10}]} & /@ 
  Delete[Tuples[RandomSample[Range[20], 7] & /@ {1, 1}], {{3}, {7}}]]
```

[image: your situation]

[image: my situation]

Answer (score 1):

### Example

```
Module[
 {data, rows, columns},

 data = Partition[row[[All, 2]], 3];
 rows = Range @ Length @ data;
 columns = Range @ Length @ First @ data;

 Grid @ Prepend[MapThread[Prepend, {data, rows}], Prepend[columns, ""]]
 ]
```